# React cancel callback when calling it multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback, use-effect

Im trying to update some code. You can change dates and when you change a day the useEffect() is called. The problem is that you can click on a new date whenever the first promise is still loading. I want to cancel the promise that is made first and only accept the last one clicked. E.g startDate = 01-04-2022 and then select 02-04-2022, 03-04-2022 etc.

```
const getData = useCallback((): void => {
    const selectedDate = dateParam ? new Date(dateParam) : new Date();

    myApiCall(selectedDate)
        .then((result: //variable here) => {
            //do stuff with result and set data
            setData(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           //if error occurs
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            //set loading to false so no memory leak can occur
            setLoading(false);
        });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    getData();

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        getData();
    }, 30000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [getData]);
```

I'm stuck on the code but I was hoping someone could help out. Thanks in advance for feedback and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` from loadash should probably help you with this.

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const yourFunction = () => {
    const selectedDate = dateParam ? new Date(dateParam) : new Date();

    myApiCall(selectedDate)
        .then((result: //variable here) => {
            //do stuff with result and set data
            setData(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
           //if error occurs
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            //set loading to false so no memory leak can occur
            setLoading(false);
        });
}

const getData = useCallback((): void => {
   debounce(yourFunction, 300) // value 300 is in ms - its just treshold you can change it to any value you want
}, []);
```

Now when user click on change date multiple times and then he stop for 3 seconds (300ms) only latest click will be trigerred