# Ignore previous callback result if state has changed in the meantime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have page displaying a list of countries provided by an external library. When I click on a country, it shows me all cities in it.
Each country object has a method to get the list of cities in it, provided by the library.
I have a `CountryComponent` like this

```js
import { City, Country } from "an-external-library";

export const CountryComponent: FC<Props> = ({ country: Country }) => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState<City[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    country
      .getCities()
      .then(setCities)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [country]);

// ...
}
```

I want to get `cities` every time the component mounts and also if the `country` changes.
The problem is that if I keep changing the country quickly, it will call `getCities()` every time I click on a country on the list. Since there's no way of knowing in which order the responses to those calls will arrive, in the end `cities` will be the response that arrived last, whatever it is.
This means I may end up with country: France; cities: New York, Los Angeles, etc...

---

**Solutions I've tried**

- Unmounting `CountryComponent` and mounting again if `country` changes.

In the parent component, I have

```js
const handleChangeCountry = (c: Country) => {
  setCountry(undefined);
  setTimeout(() => setCountry(c), 10);
}

render (
  <>
    <CountryList onCountryClick={handleChangeCountry}/>
    {country ?
      <CountryComponent country={country}/>
    :
      <Spinner />
    })
  </>
)
```

This a solution so ugly that just writing this gives me the creeps.
But it worked.
Just that I couldn't get the UI to look clean when the `CountryComponent` disappeared for 10  ms and appeared again; and want a better solution.

---

**Solutions I haven't tried**

As suggested by @chimera, `debouncing` could be a solution.
While searching for solutions before posting, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71783444/1971089), but didn't try it because I believe that it would cause the list of cities to take a while to respond to clicks on countries, and that's not ideal either.

---

Ideally, I would like to ignore all callbacks from `getCities()` except the last, but I don't know how I'd achieve this.

Comment: I think you will have to debounce the request that you're doing in the useEffect. That way you can take only the last one that you did, the previous ones would get removed. Let me elaborate a bit on it

Comment: When searching for solutions online, I found the "debouncing" one, but I haven't tried it yet because I believe it will have the drawback of the cities list taking a while to respond to clicking on another country, and that's not ideal either. But thanks for suggesting!

Comment: Have you tried react-query? Since this is server-state it might be a good library to have, and not 100% sure but I think they solve this issue

Comment: I haven't, but I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I just set up a sandox with rq, not precisely the same as your case but kind of https://codesandbox.io/s/rq-test-countries-ld4bsp

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue: you get unordered asynchronous responses, potentially overwriting the most recent (and the only relevant) state.

A very easy solution is to use [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use)'s [`useAsync`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md) hook, which includes several useful mechanisms for this typical issue, the one interesting here being that it discards the responses of every previous requests, keeping only the response to the most recent request.

> React hook that resolves an async function or a function that returns a promise;

```
import { useAsync } from "react-use";

const CountryComponent = ({ country: Country }) => {
  // With react-use's useAsync,
  // no need for separate state and useEffect
  const cities = useAsync(
    () => country.getCities(),
    [country]
  ).value; // returned object { loading: boolean, value: T, error }
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will probably be useful, even if I have to modify it a bit since I do need to have cities as state because of the infinite scroll (I didn't mention it in the post).

Comment: You can easily still use a state, by assigning its value within the useAsync callback, in a similar way as you were doing it in useEffect, instead of using the result of useAsync.